# Css para test con radio button

Tags: css

He intentado hacer una página con una serie de preguntas con respuesta A B o C.

He visto el Css para ocultar el radio button, pero no hay forma de q al hacer click en la celda correspondiente se quede TODA la celda con un color de fondo concreto.

He probado algún ejemplo en el q visto q usan una label, pero no hay manera. Y me da la impresión de q tampoco tiene q ser tan tan complicado.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy ambigua, por favor re-formúlala explicando de manera concreta lo que quieres y pon algo de código para apoyar la explicación

Comment: deberias de publicar el codigo que ya tienes para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos parte de tu código y alguna imagen del resultado?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que intentas hacer se basa en esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        label {
            background: lightblue;
            margin:  .5rem;
            padding: .5rem;
        }
        .content {
            border-radius: 5px;
            border:  1px solid grey;
            margin:  1rem 2rem;
            padding: 1rem;
        }
        .item-content {
            margin:  1rem;
            padding: 1rem;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .none {
            display: none;
        }

        /* Mostrar bloques de contenido ocultos */
        #show-toggle1:checked~#toggle1,
        #show-toggle2:checked~#toggle2
        {
            display: block !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">

        <label for="show-toggle1">
            Lorem ipsum 1
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-toggle1" class="none">
        <div class="item-content none" id="toggle1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus fugit doloribus accusantium impedit. Consequatur ratione a facere laborum aliquid repellendus nulla libero, nam, eos facilis nobis fuga, est vero cupiditate!
        </div>

        <label for="show-toggle2">
            Lorem ipsum 2
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-toggle2" class="none">
        <div class="item-content none" id="toggle2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum minima quo libero deleniti nam consequatur, consectetur autem doloremque quae voluptatibus itaque, cum debitis vitae. Itaque accusantium ipsum consequuntur eos saepe.
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hay dos cuadros activables (mediante click) asociados a sendos *checkboxes* ocultos que a su vez modifican los estilos de cajas de contenido mostrándolas u ocultándolas, según el estado de los checkboxes.

La técnica es sencilla pero **debe aplicarse de un modo concreto** y **tiene limitaciones**. Por ejemplo, mover el `label` asociado al `checkbox` en el documento funciona, aunque sea a otra caja, por ejemplo la siguiente modificación aun funcionaría:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="show-toggle1">
            Lorem ipsum 1
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-toggle1" class="none">
        <div class="item-content none" id="toggle1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
        </div>

        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

o esta otra:

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-toggle1" class="none">
        <div class="item-content none" id="toggle1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
        </div>

        ...
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="show-toggle1">
            Lorem ipsum 1
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
```

Pero **el `checkbox` asociado a una *caja de contenido* debe estar al mismo nivel que ésta** (deben ser hermanos) **y aparecer antes**, es decir lo siguiente no funciona:

```
<div>
    <label for="show-toggle1">
        Lorem ipsum 1
    </label>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-toggle1" class="none">
<div class="content">
    <div class="item-content none" id="toggle1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
    </div>
</div>
```

tampoco lo siguiente:

```
<div>
    <label for="show-toggle1">
        Lorem ipsum 1
    </label>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="item-content none" id="toggle1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-toggle1" class="none">
</div>
```

Entonces, aquí **lo importante es la posición del `checkbox` que va a controlar una caja de contenido con respecto a ésta**.

En cuanto a las limitaciones, se aplica estilo a una caja concreta si usas su ID para controlarla o a varias, usando clases CSS. Puedes aplicarles visibilidad, un color de fondo u otros efectos que requieras:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    
        <style type="text/css">
            label {
                background: lightblue;
                margin:  .5rem;
                padding: .5rem;
            }
            .content {
                border-radius: 5px;
                border:  1px solid grey;
                margin:  1rem 2rem;
                padding: 1rem;
            }
            .item-content {
                margin:  1rem;
                padding: 1rem;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .none {
                display: none;
            }
    
            /* Mostrar colores de fondo */
            #show-toggle1:checked~#toggle1,
            #show-toggle2:checked~#toggle2
            {
                background: darkblue;
                border:  2px solid red;
                color:   white;
                display: block !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <label for="show-toggle1">
                Cambiar estilos
            </label>
    
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-toggle1" class="none">
            <div class="item-content" id="toggle1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            label {
                background: lightblue;
                margin:  .5rem;
                padding: .5rem;
            }
            .content {
                border-radius: 5px;
                border:  1px solid grey;
                margin:  1rem 2rem;
                padding: 1rem;
            }
            .item-content {
                margin:  1rem;
                padding: 1rem;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .none {
                display: none;
            }

            #action-cb:checked~#action-aim,
            #action-cb-xxx:checked~.zzz
            {
                background: pink;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <label for="action-cb">
                Cambiar estilos texto
            </label>
            <label for="action-cb-xxx">
                Cambiar estilos con clases CSS
            </label>

            <input type="checkbox" id="action-cb" class="none">
            <div class="content" id="action-aim">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" id="action-cb-xxx" class="none">
            <div class="item-content zzz">Caja controlada con clase CSS</div>
            <div class="item-content zzz">Caja controlada con clase CSS</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Pero teniendo en cuanta siempre la posición del checkboxes y de las cajas que controlan.

Comment: está increíble tu respuesta

Comment: @Mariyselita muchas gracias.

Comment: Es realmente espectacular!. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Gracias a la generosidad de gente como tú, el resto podemos aprender!